# Large XML File - Appending to Pandas DF - Increasingly Slow

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I am trying to put XML into a usable data format, so I chose a pandas dataframe. Below is some code that goes through my XML tree and pulls the data I need for each datapoint. The problem is that there are about 632,000 lines. My code gets slower and slower to the point that it is quickly requiring 100 seconds to go through a 1000 iterations. I feel it should be relatively linear in time to go through each datapoint, but something is slowing it down.

Any advice?

I can provide full code and link to dataset if need be.

Thanks.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(path+xname)
root = tree.getroot()
data = pd.DataFrame(None,columns=["GEO","AGE","SEX","YEAR","VALUE"])
b = time.time()
c = len(root[1])

for i in range(1,range(len(root[1])):
    if i % 1000 == 0:
        a = time.time()
        print (a - b)
        b = time.time()
    data = data.append({"GEO":root[1][i][0][0].attrib["value"], \
                        "AGE":root[1][i][0][1].attrib["value"], \
                        "SEX":root[1][i][0][2].attrib["value"], \
                        "TIME":root[1][i][1][0].text, \
                        "VALUE":root[1][i][1][1].attrib["value"]}, \
                       ignore_index=True)
    root[1][i].clear()
```

Comment: It's usually better to build a list of dataframes in loop and then concatenate outside to avoid expanding a dataframe in place. How large is XML? >1 GB?

Comment: No, only 250MB. Would it even be better to just append it to a list? Just get a list of lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you want to build the entire dataset before passing it to the data frame constructor.  Appending is very slow because it is creating a an entire new data frame from scratch on the backend.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd

tree = ET.parse(path+xname)
root = tree.getroot()

data = []
for i in range(1, range(len(root[1])):
    data.append((root[1][i][0][0].attrib["value"], 
                 root[1][i][0][1].attrib["value"], 
                 root[1][i][0][2].attrib["value"], 
                 root[1][i][1][0].text, 
                 root[1][i][1][1].attrib["value"]))

df = pd.DataFrame(data ,columns=["GEO","AGE","SEX","YEAR","VALUE"])
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried it with a dictionary and it parsed the entire dataset in 4 seconds, whereas my original code was taking 4 second to complete the first 1000 passes of the for loop.